# SwiftUI: after screen lock List doesn't have core data objects, empty views

Tags: core-data, swiftui

When using SwiftUI with Core Data via @FetchRequest and displaying data in list it works ok.
But if i lock the screen using right side button and unlock again application loads with empty state and displays no data on screen. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar items default code is broken in SwiftUI:  Use this in the template code.
Embed the List into a NavigationView and then The buttons in a HStack.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView { //added
    List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
    } .toolbar {
        
                    #if os(iOS)
                    HStack {  //added
                        EditButton()
                        Button(action: addItem) {
                            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }//added
                    #endif

    }
    }//added NavView embed
}
```